# Training Plan for the Bodybuilding

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, gym, physique, muscle-growth

A NASM-CPT (National Academy of Sports Medicine-certified personal trainer) trainer said that the training for the bodybuilding should consist of both muscle building period and max strength developing period. In this way, one can enhance the strength and build muscle efficiently. For example, one can use 60 Kg for the barbell bench press. To enhance the strength, one should adapt the max strength training for 8-12 weeks; then, he/she could use more weight (e.g. 70 kg) for the bench press.

I wonder whether this is true or not? Is this the only standard way for the body building training in the gym?

If one only wants to have a better body-shape/body-building; not the powerlifting performance, and only adapts muscle building training; without the max strength developing period, can he/she enhance more strength for the exercise efficiently and gain good body building result?

Would anyone please give me some explanations?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the NASM claim? Having that is necessary to understand the context of their claims, which is necessary for answering this question.

Comment: @Thomas Markov Thank you for the reply. Honestly, I am just an amateur in the bodybuilding. When I did the exercise in the gym, a fitness coach there talked with me. He obtained the NASM-CPT (certified personal trainer) qualification and he told me that one should adapt both muscle building period and max strength developing period for the training if he/she wants to enhance the strength for the bodybuilding. I am not sure if this is true or not. Would you please give me some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thomas Markov At this moment, I only adapt the muscle building training for the bodybuilding. I mean I do 12 reps for each set now. I never did the 5 reps with heavy weight for any set before. Is my training not that efficient or not that correct for the body building? I really appreciate if you could provide some suggestions/comments?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then the question would probably be improved by saying something like “a NASM certified trainer told me” rather than “according to NASM”. I’ve heard NASM certified trainers say some pretty silly things that NASM certainly did not endorse.

Comment: @Thomas Markov Thank you. In other words, it is not necessary to adapt both muscle building period and max strength developing period for the body building. Only with the muscle building training without any max strength development, one could also have good body building result. Am I correct?

Comment: There are different approaches for bodybuilding training, some say you need dedicated strength phases and some say you don't.  It seems both approaches get results in the long run - it's not a quick process anyway. Also both size build strength and vice versa, you can pick whatever path you prefer.

Comment: @Luciano Thank you for the suggestions. I think that I will keep on doing the muscle building training; not the max strength development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NASM's training focus is primarily *sports* training. That's a very generic and broad approach. It's not exclusive to bodybuilding.

The build/strength/build/strength approach is a great approach to build a well-rounded athletic person. It's also good for beginners and intermediates to build a baseline, or people who want a healthy lifestyle. Having a good strength baseline can help prevent injuries and prolong training.

Though most of the time, people who compete will train exclusively for their sport. People who compete exclusively in bodybuilding almost always have hypertrophy phases. Their training changes depending on what body parts needs to be built, but the focus is always building/maintaining mass.

Likewise, strength athletes will almost always train for strength. They sometimes have hypertrophy phases in the off-season, but for the most part they do strength.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions with so many details. What I want is to use more weight for my training; for example, I am using 60 Kg for the barbell bench press and I want to increase to 70 Kg; however, I feel difficult to fulfill the 12 reps with 70 Kg. I can only do 8 reps for the press now. Do you think that I can achieve the 12 reps with 70 Kg much more sooner if I adapt the maximal strength development? Or do you think I do not need any maximal strength development; just keep on the hypertrophy and I can do the 12 reps with 70 Kg sooner or later? Thank you again.

Comment: @Kieran I think either strategy would probably help you get to 12 reps at 70kg. One thing you can try is instead of focusing on a 12-rep weight, just increase the intensity to your 8-rep weight.  You can do 70 kg now, so next time you attempt it, try 72.5 kg for 8.  If you can hit that, then try 75 kg for 8. If you miss that and say get 6, then hold at 75 kg and attempt to get 7 the following bench workout.

Comment: The main thing is you should be attempting a little bit more every workout.  So if you choose to stay at 60 kg, then attempt to get 13 reps, and then 14, and then 15, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. It is really helpful. I will try more weight for bench press with 8 reps.